# AWS SNS push notification not received on iPhone 6 and above

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns, devicetoken

My coworker and I are building an app and implementing push notification feature utilizing AWS SNS API.
The issue here is that some devices work fine but some like iPhone 6,7,8 receive no notification regardless of the OS version (they're mostly iOS 11,12).

We've covered the basic by checking the below points:

> 1. notification turned on on all test devices
> 2. testers grant permission to receive notification at the app launch time
> 3. the p12 certificate uploaded to AWS is valid and the format is correct

The error messages we got from AWS CloudWatch Logs mostly were "bad device token" or "unregistered", but we are sure that we upload the device token as soon as we got it from APNS.

**EDIT: actual code added**

Register for notification (within `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`)

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { granted, error in
    if let error = error {
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    } else {
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
}
```

Get token

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    print("Successfully registered for notifications!")
 // upload token to our database for later use
}
```

Is there anything we are missing?

Comment: show your code, how did you get device token? Also, check whether u have accepted notification when u launched the app on the device.  You can check in setting section of your app.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS Devices of older models work fine running the same code, I'm wondering if there is any change Apple made for the software upgrade that AWS hasn't configure their API to be compatible.

Comment: @devdork Can you post a code snippet where you are using the Amazon SNS API from your app? What version of iOS and AWS iOS SDK are you using?